# Stripe charge not going through

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

I'm using the Stripe API to test out charges and the charge is not going through. I tokenize the credit card then use the token as a "source" parameter. I did the exact same thing in Python and it worked fine, but when I tried using this with Node.js, it didn't work.

Here's my code:

```
var stripe = require("stripe")(<key>);

var pay = stripe.tokens.create({
  card: {
   number: '<number>',    // note, for now I'm just using the stripe test credentials
   exp_month: <exp>,
   exp_year: <year>,
   cvc: '<cvc>'
}
}, function(err, token) {
  console.log(err); // null
  console.log(token); // token information (works fine)
  return token;
});

stripe.charges.create({
  amount: 500,
  currency: "usd",
  source: pay, 
  description: "Test charge"
  }, function(err, charge) {
   console.log(err); // error message 400, missing parameter
   console.log(charge); //  still null
 });
```

What am I doing wrong? As I said, when I did this using Python it worked fine.

**Update:** I've tried all solutions posted below and they all still return a error 400 code. If anyone has another solution it would be appreciated.

**_____________________________________________________________________________**
**Update 2:** For anyone looking for an answer, I figured it out and posted it below.

Comment: `currency: "usd,` ? missing a quote?

Comment: Typo on my part but not the problem, still gives me the 400 error

Comment: Are you sure you're creating the token properly?

Comment: As far as I know I am, it prints everything out in the console the exact same way they have it in the docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who wants to create charges this way, here is how i figured it out with Node.js (for people like me who came from python, this will be very helpful):

```
stripe.tokens.create({
card: {
    number: '<card number>',
    exp_month: <exp>,
    exp_year: <year>,
    cvc: '<cvc>'
}
}, function(err, token) {
   console.log(token.id); // you can log the entire token, or you can just check for the piece you need
   stripe.charges.create({
      amount: 800,
      currency: "usd",
      source: token.id,  // instead of in python where you can use a variable, in node you have to use specifically the id
      description: "Test charge"
  }, function(err, charge) {
      console.log(err);  // if it does not work, make sure to print the error
      console.log(charge) // print the charge to make sure it went through
   });
});
```

Hopefully this will help someone along the road!

**Note:** As others mentioned, for production this is probably not what you want to do, this solution would more be for getting to know the Stripe API or testing out quick charges.

Answer (score 1):

The `create` methods run asynchronously. If you want to use the token you just created, then you need to do so in the callback. To better understand this, check this code:

```
var stripe = require("stripe")(<key>);

var pay = stripe.tokens.create({
  card: {
   number: '<number>',    // note, for now I'm just using the stripe test credentials
   exp_month: <exp>,
   exp_year: <year>,
   cvc: '<cvc>'
}, function(err, token) {
  console.log(err); // null
  console.log(token); // token information (works fine)
  return token;
});

console.log(pay); // This will not be what you expected.
```

`pay` is not going to be the value of `token` because the request hasn’t finished yet.

Instead, you need to create your charge inside the callback for the token. This callback function is executed once the web request for the token creation is finished.

```
var stripe = require("stripe")(<key>);

stripe.tokens.create({
  card: {
   number: '<number>',    // note, for now I'm just using the stripe test credentials
   exp_month: <exp>,
   exp_year: <year>,
   cvc: '<cvc>'
}, function(err, token) {
  console.log(err); // null
  console.log(token); // token information (works fine)
  stripe.charges.create({
    amount: 500,
    currency: "usd",
    source: token, // note I changed this to token 
    description: "Test charge"
  }, function(err, charge) {
    console.log(err); // hopefully null now 
    console.log(charge); // hopefully has charge info now
    // add code to display a confirmation message or whatever you want to do with the successful charge here
  });
});
```

Disclaimer: I’m not familiar with the Stripe code. I just understand how asynchronous JS works. Creating the token every time may or may not be best practice.

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

1. `stripe.tokens.create` returns a Promise, not a value. You have to assign `token` to something in the right scope to use it elsewhere, or just pass it to a function that uses it:

```
stripe.tokens.create({
  card: {
    number: '<number>',    // note, for now I'm just using the stripe test credentials
    exp_month: <exp>,
    exp_year: <year>,
    cvc: '<cvc>'
  }
}, function(err, token) {
  console.log(err); // null
  console.log(token); // token information (works fine)

  // call a function which in turn calls stripe.charges.create
  makeCharge(token);
});
```

2. You shouldn't be generating tokens on your backend, this subjects you to the widest scope of PCI compliance https://stripe.com/docs/security#validating-pci-compliance. Instead use Stripe Elements or legacy Checkout on your frontend to tokenize cards.
3. JavaScript is asynchronous rather than synchronous, look into using [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) if you want synchronous operations.

Answer (score 1):

You can do one think just use the default source from the stripe customer id created by user.

```
return stripe.customers.retrieve(stripeCustomerId)
                .then((customer) => customer.default_source)
```

You will get the customer default source if available and after that just create charge using this source.

```
const strpChrg = {
            customer: stripeCustomerId,
            amount: _.round(amount * 100), // convert to cents
            currency: _.toLower(currency), // usd
            source: sourceId
 };
 // create stripe charge using customer token
 return stripe.charges.create(strpChrg).then((charge) => {
            // add charge to data
            return charge;
 });
```

You should not create a token at the backend, use stripe default source added by the customer instead.